# Linq Stored Uppercase table columns

Tags: linq, uppercase

I have a stored procedure which returns a table as a result of a `SELECT` statement in it. I want to turn one column to uppercase on Linq when clicking on a button.

The stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetAllEmps](@PKID int) AS
IF @PKID = -1
SELECT * FROM Employee
ELSE
SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE EmpId= @PKID
```

Comment: *I want* ... So, where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Why you need LINQ for that? Just use *.ToUpper()* method

```
SomeStringValue = SomeStringValue.ToUpper();
```